# What are the most yeasty fruits sold in supermarkets suitable for providing yeast for making bread?

Tags: bread, fruit, yeast, shopping

Various fresh fruits, such as grapes, apricots, and dates, can be used to provide the yeast that is needed in breadmaking. But often in commercial production fruits are sprayed with pesticides, and then later they are washed, and therefore when they are sold in supermarkets they do not have much yeast left.

What fruits sold in supermarkets, whether fresh or dried, are most suitable for providing yeast for making bread?

Comment: Are you looking to make a sourdough starter, or another application?

Comment: @GdD - Not necessarily. But I'd be interested in answers that involve a sourdough starter as well as those that don't.

Comment: I would assume that production methods (e.g. non-treated, organic) are more influential than species?

Comment: There are certain fruits that are less likely to be washed, due to perishability (like grapes), and others that tend to be washed and waxed (like apples), and I _want_ to say that might be related to wild yeast content, but I have no idea.

Comment: Raisins, which is to say grapes of a certain type that have been dried, are mentioned quite a lot as a good source of yeast for breadmaking, but I don't know whether this includes standard raisins sold in supermarkets. Hopefully it does.

Comment: I doubt you can harvest enough natural yeast from fruit to make bread.  The process will surely require a starter to be created so that you propagate enough yeast and bacteria to leaven a loaf.

Comment: @moscafj I must disagree. I have made bread with the dredges from elderflower champagne (posted a photo in our chat), made yeast water from apples and elderflower, and soaking raisins in sugar water is almost “standard procedure” for some bakers.

Comment: @Stephie I am not sure we disagree, unless you are suggesting that you can use the yeast straight from the fruit without creating some sort of starter or method to propagate the existing yeast and bacteria so that there is enough leavening power.

Comment: @moscafj ah. But it’s significantly easier than getting a full-blown sourdough culture. A bit of water, maybe sugar and a few days is all it takes. I kind of assumed that the OP was aware of that and not just planning to throw apple peels in a dough and hope for a spectacular rise ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Yeast on the surface of fruit and even flowers is a quite normal occurrence. For a start, I would recommend *fruit that are commonly fermented for alcoholic drinks*, so my first choice would be **apples** or **grapes** - also because they are quite easily obtained. Note that the yeast is on the skins, so using just peels or small fruit like berries or grapes is better.

*However*, any kind of “treatment” may interfere with the naturally yeasts on the skins, so I would recommend buying **organic fruit** and perhaps even skip washing them (ok, that’s probably debatable and personal choice). If you can get your hands on fruit straight from a garden or similar, that would be better than any fruit that’s been through a commercial packaging process and sat on shelves for a while. They may also have picked up mold spores that are harmless when you use the fruit as usual, but can increase the risk of failure for yeast harvesting. You also want fruit to be harvested as mature as possible, to get high sugar levels and subsequently high yeast levels - just to get things started faster.

During the recent Covid crisis and lockdown, some stores ran out of commercial yeast and while sourdough can be a substitute, yeast water had its renaissance, because it’s a faster method and can be made with fruit from storage. The probably most used candidates are **raisins**, but figs, dates and everything that gets dried with the skin can work. Note that raisins have a particularly high surface to volume ratio, so the yield is quite good. Apart from making sure you get the skins (which is theoretically enough, you don’t need the flesh for yeast), you also want untreated pure fruit, so neither sulfur-treatment (for „brighter“ fruit and preservation) nor those poached in sugar, like it’s often done for cranberries and other sour fruit.
Not part of your question, but maybe worth an experiment: some flowers have a high yeast content, so soaking a few elderflowers in sugar water gives you the same results as the raisins, but it’s a seasonal thing - and I have read (but not tested) about linden and sunflowers as good nectar yeast sources.

Comment: +1, except I would doubt the apples - they are quite frequently treated (including the organic ones, which get waxed).

Comment: Apples may depend on source - if they aren’t washed (-> stripped off their natural wax), there’s no need to add artificial wax. It’s also country-specific: Apples produced and sold in Germany are rarely waxed and it’s not permitted for organic apples. Other regulations may apply elsewhere. The US allows waxing for organic fruit, but limits the kind of wax. For some cultivars the natural wax layer is thicker, so there’s no need to add any. That may be worth further investigation.

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer that is very practical for those who shop in British supermarkets is **bilberries**. These tend to be covered with a white powder which surely almost certainly contains a lot of yeast. I am in the process of testing this hypothesis.

Comment: So, how did your experiment turn out?

Answer (score 0):

Dried persimmon have a white bloomy coat or soon will after purchase.

This gal produces 'water yeast' for baking; details about her attempt with persimmon:

https://www.thefreshloaf.com/node/49639/park-tae-young-yeast-water-chronicles

Comment: I would suspect that the white bloom on dried persimmons are sugar crystals? - Yep, the article says so too.

Comment: Ate a lot of them in Beijing; yeastie beasties. Super gross when it gets thick and dusty. Can just scrape and rinse.